# Conditional plotting in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with x-axis as  carrier names and y-axis as some values ranging from 1.00 to 4.00
How can I apply color to the bars as per the condition: if value of a name is greater than 2 make the bar red else make it green.

My code till now is :

```
ggplot(plotdf,aes(x=dft1.Carrier_Name,y=newvar$nn))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+coord_flip()
```

I tried with scale_fill_color and

```
col = ifelse(y > 2,'red','green')
```

> head(plotdf)

```
dft1.Carrier_Name newvar.nn

1                9E 2.7077740

2                AA 2.8831927

3                AQ 0.5384615

4                AS 1.4156001

5                B6 1.6344452

6                CO 1.2403880
```

But no luck till now! Please help. I am a bit new to R.

Comment: there should be some other ways, for me I will make another variable with that condition on y-axis value and fill=this.variable

Comment: can u give an example for the same .. will it be diff from what I gave with col=ifelse...

Comment: can you post head of you data? with `dput(head(plotdf,10))`

Comment: > head(plotdf)
  dft1.Carrier_Name newvar.nn
1                9E 2.7077740
2                AA 2.8831927
3                AQ 0.5384615
4                AS 1.4156001
5                B6 1.6344452
6                CO 1.2403880

Comment: > dput(head(plotdf,10))
structure(list(dft1.Carrier_Name = structure(1:10, .Label = c("9E", 
"AA", "AQ", "AS", "B6", "CO", "DL", "EV", "F9", "FL", "HA", "MQ", 
"NW", "OH", "OO", "UA", "US", "WN", "XE", "YV"), class = "factor"), 
    newvar.nn = c(2.70777398096168, 2.88319267298743, 0.538461538461538, 
    1.41560005823881, 1.63444523206062, 1.24038799819068, 1.50753101690302, 
    1.79132139356678, 0.31640943171613, 0.854465691444643)), .Names = c("dft1.Carrier_Name", 
"newvar.nn"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: edit on question, than here, it can be better formated over there. Didi you try my answer below?

Comment: I ll edit the quest first and Yes am trying..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edited to include answer for actual data

```
df=structure(list(dft1.Carrier_Name = structure(1:10, .Label = c("9E", "AA", "AQ", "AS", "B6", "CO", "DL", "EV", "F9", "FL", "HA", "MQ", "NW", "OH", "OO", "UA", "US", "WN", "XE", "YV"), class = "factor"), newvar.nn = c(2.70777398096168, 2.88319267298743, 0.538461538461538, 1.41560005823881, 1.63444523206062, 1.24038799819068, 1.50753101690302, 1.79132139356678, 0.31640943171613, 0.854465691444643)), .Names = c("dft1.Carrier_Name", "newvar.nn"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame") 

df$dummy<-ifelse(df$newvar.nn>2,T,F)
ggplot(df,aes(dft1.Carrier_Name, newvar.nn, fill=dummy))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

try this on your dataframe, I created df here because you did not provide

```
x<-c("a","b","c","d")
df<-data.frame(x=x,z=1:4)
df$dummy<-ifelse(df$z<=2,T,F)
ggplot(df,aes(x, y, fill=dummy))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Following from this, do you know a way that I could only plot count values above a certain threshold? I have a long data frame with Depth, Element, Value and I'm simply using geom_bar(aes(Depth) to plot the number of occurrences of Depth. I'd like to subset and only plot when there are more than 6 occurrences of Depth.

Comment: @JJGabe Please see the filter function from tidyverse family of packages.

Comment: I know the filter function but I am unsure of how to set the masking arguments so that it only selects the Depths that occur more than a set number of times, say 6. My data is in long format and the Depth values repeat between 0 and 8 times e.g. `Depth <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0)` (that vector is part of the first column of my df). I'm using `geom_bar(aes(Depth))` to plot the counts of each Depth value